# Проблема с установкой компилятора в CMake.CMake не может найти компилятор,хотя он есть

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Я новичок в программировании на `С` и `С++` и у меня возникла проблема. Для того чтобы скомпилировать библиотеку `CSFML`, мне понадобился `CMake`. Но как только я попытался сконфигурировать проект в `CMake gui`, выскакивает ошибка:

> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to
>   "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need
>   to select a different build tool. CMake Error: CMake was unable to
>   find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles". 
>   CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a
>   different build tool. CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after
>   EnableLanguage CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after
>   EnableLanguage

Проблема в том,что `CMake` как бы я не старался не может найти компиляторы, хотя они прописаны в переменной среды `PATH`. Если же запускать `CMake` из командной строки, то он пишет:

> file does not exist

или

> not contain CMakeLists.txt

Но файл то существует, а `CMakeLists.txt` там и не должно существовать

Я загуглил и посмотрел ответы на примерно такие же вопросы, но не нашёл внятного ответа. Я посмотрел тучу разных источников, а также официальную документацию,но ничего не помогло.

*Версия СMake 3.12.3, установлена с официального сайта.

Операционная система Windows XP SP3.

Компилятор GCC MinGW.*

Comment: Вместо слова "ложно" видимо хотели написать "должно"?

Comment: Да,спасибо за указание на ошибку

Comment: Только я правильно понимаю, что ``Операционная система Windows XP SP3.`` && ``Новичок в программировании`` = ничего хорошего не получится?

Comment: в аргументах cmake'а передал `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` и  `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` команду запуска компилятора? и на случай, если в PATH всё же не прописаны, с полными путями?

Comment: Все ж в тексте ошибки написано. Надо указать `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` (mingw32-make.exe), указать папку с CMakeLists.txt, поставить нормальную ОС.

Answer (score 0):

В `cmake-gui` красным подсвечиваются неустановленные или неправильно установленные переменные `cmake`. Просто вручную укажите пути к нужным файлам для таких переменных. И лучше проверить ещё раз корректность установки `MinGW`.