# не получается использовать cmake с помощью команды " cmake .."

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw, файловые-пути

Команда:

```
cmake ..
```

Ошибка:

> C:\Programming\cpgpsens\cpgpsens\build>cmake ..
>
> CMake Error at
>
> CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):   Running
>
> 'nmake' '-?'
>
> failed with:
>
> Не удается найти указанный файл
>
> **CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage**
>
> **CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage**
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Компилятор MinGW, пути в системных переменных к компилятору прописаны:
[image: PATH]
[image: CMAKE_C/CXX_COMPILER]
[image: переменные среды пользователя nastystuffy]
[image: комментарий пользователя @arrowd]

Пробовал:

Гуглить(решение конкретно моей проблемы [видел только для линукса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140273/cmake-c-compiler-is-not-a-full-path-to-an-existing-compiler-tool), где нужно было экспортировать(export) переменную, вписав название и путь к bin файлу), перезагружать пк, переустанавливать компиляторы, CMake, удалять всё, что связанно с C/C++ на компьютере и скачивать заного , менять компиляторы(gcc, clang, Visual Studio, окончательно остановился на MinGW, вроде как самый стабильный), пробовал на чистой Windows 10, в виртуальной машине, установить CMake и MinGW, написать лёгкий проект и CMakeLists.txt, (на виртуальную машину никаких IDE не устанавливал, писал всё в блокноте, на основной машине IDE - Visual Studio Code), на другой диск установил linux, скопировал код и структуру файлов ({ src, build, CMakeLists.txt } -> в одной папке) -> установил cmake -> cd build -> cmake .. -> без ошибок, проблем и прочего, пробовал решение пользователя [@arrowd в комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/892767/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-cmake-cmake-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%BE), добавил переменную(можно увидеть на скриншоте(3 ряд), пробовал устанавливать Visual Studio 2022, со всеми компонентами для C/C++ - безрезультатно

Comment: сейчас вы заставляете cmake генерировать сборочный скрипт для vc++, о чем не двусмысленно написано в логе. Если бы имелись установленные инструменты Visual Studio 2022, то оно бы работало. А если хотите сгенерировать make файлы, то это следует явно указать соотв. генератор посредством директивы `CMAKE_GENERATOR`. `пути в системных переменных`  - не трогайте системные переменные.

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что если вы используете компиляторы, установленные через Visual Studio, то вам сначала надо установить окружение VS. Для этого вам нужен vcvars64.bat. Он лежит по пути `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Версия\Версия\VC\Auxiliary\Build`. Из консоли зовете этот батник, он проставит все переменные окружения для Visual Studio, в том числе и пути к компиляторам. И уже потом зовете cmake. Только учитывайте, что при таком запуске генератор по умолчанию будет вижловский и на выходе вы получите .sln файл

Answer (score -1):

Укажите тип генерируемых файлов, добавив "`-G "MinGW Makefiles`".